# Val_accuracy (val_acc) very low

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, convolution

We have a data set that is converted from signal data to video. We want to classify these images using convolution. We tried many different methods but val acc is consistently low. Training accuracy is 99% and val_acc is 40%. We need your help in this respect. Thank you

```
weight_decay=0.0005
input_ = Input(shape=(125, 125, 1))
# Block 1
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same',kernel_regularizer='0.001')(input_)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='pool1')(x)

# Block 2
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same',kernel_regularizer='0.001')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='pool2')(x)

# Block 3
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same',kernel_regularizer='0.001')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same',kernel_regularizer='0.001')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='pool3')(x)

# Block 4
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same',kernel_regularizer='0.001')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same',kernel_regularizer='0.001')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='pool4')(x)
x = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)

x = Dense(800,kernel_regularizer='0.001')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(800,kernel_regularizer='0.001')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dense(8)(x)
x = Activation('softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs = input_, outputs=x)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll7sg.png)

my kernel and dataset
https://www.kaggle.com/ultrasonraporlama/video-kernel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding dropout layers to your network, this should work very well to reduce the amount of overfitting of your network.

Comment: I added the last 2 dense layers. but the result has not changed

Comment: I said dropout, so `keras.layers.Dropout`, which I do not see in your code example.

Comment: it doesn't appear in my current code, but I've tried to add it later. the result has not changed.

Comment: Between which layers have you added the dropout layer(s) and what dropout percentage did you use?

Comment: I've tried every possibility between 0.1 and 0.5.
also when I add kernel_regularizer = 0.01, train acc and vall_acc do not exceed 50% .kernel_regularizer = 0.001 when I add train acc, after a certain epoch, 90% comes out but val_acc cannot pass 40%

Comment: But between which layers did you add the dropout layer? From the kaggle kernel which you've linked I only see a dropout layer between the last two dense layers. You should try adding them to the earlier dense layers as well.

Comment: val_acc was the best 45% I could find. I did what you said. but not.

Comment: Can you try again  https://www.kaggle.com/ultrasonraporlama/video-kernel/

Comment: That one works. Also, what makes you think that you should be able to get more than 45% accuracy on your out of sample data?

Comment: I achieved 90% success with  machine learning methods svm, knn

Comment: What is the classification that you are trying to achieve? From what I can see from the kernel is that you are feeding the model grey scale images [like this one](https://i.imgur.com/fwtKyka.png).

Comment: these images belong to the signals. I converted the signals into images. I'm trying to classify these images.

Comment: I don't see anything that can directly improve performance. Maybe it's good to try and add more data since you only have a total of 900 examples for the 8 different classes (or try transfer learning, but looking at your code it seems as though you've already tried that). Otherwise I'd probably stick with SVM/KNN since they achieved a high validation accuracy.

Comment: I tried transfer learning. unfortunately the result has not changed. thank you so much

Comment: Hi, what exactly have you tried with regards to transfer learning? Have the nets you used been trained for similar data? Have you adjusted the network architecture? have you retrained it?

Comment: hi,yes I tried. however, these images are not a classic image. I have fully trained the network but the result has not changed. With vgg, the results are very poor. With mobilenet, the results turned out better. but did not exceed 45%.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using VGG-16 so make sure you have a good number of examples for each classes else it will overfitt. Secondly VGG-16 takes in an input of 224x224. So, please change it and see.

I think for your usecase, you should use a custom model rather than VGG-16 because the network might not map your data correctly to the corresponding classes.

Comment: thank you. I tried it with different models. however, the result has not changed.